# CodeIgniter 3 closing session warning on unlink session file

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, localhost, unlink

I'm using CodeIgniter 3 to develop a web app and Ion **Auth** to manage users' login and logout, I'm using it on localhost on Windows. On logout I got this warning:

**Severity: Warning**

> Message: unlink(
>   my_path_to_sessions\ci_session04c5acf96846fedf1fa448278e16a4006f6a10a0): Permission denied Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php Line
>   Number: 303

My Session_files_driver at line numbers 302-304:

```
return file_exists($this->_file_path.$session_id)
? (unlink($this->_file_path.$session_id) && $this->_cookie_destroy())
: TRUE;
```

In my config file I've set:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH.'sessions/';
```

I've also changed permissions for sessions folder.

What's the problem?

Comment: Changed the permissions to what?

Comment: Properties > Security: Users --> Full control, but I not sure it was the right thing to do

Comment: This is a CI bug. It will not happen in production server. This problems only in windows and when simultaneous ajax call running. However you may try reload twice the logout link to fix it

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Yes, if I retry logout it doesn't give me this error and everything works fine. So the problem will disappear on the real server?

Answer (score 0):

I have added the **constructor** in controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

which causing this issue so I have **removed** it and **now** it's **working** like charm.